# Can't create vpn adapter on lubuntu 16.04

Tags: vpn, vpnc

Today I tried to connect to my Fritz!Box VPN and it failed to connect. I followed [this instruction](https://en.avm.de/service/vpn/tips-tricks/setting-up-a-vpn-connection-to-fritzbox-in-linux/).

I installed vpnc via the cli. After that I switched to my network manager (xfce) and clicked on **vpn -> configure -> add -> type:** <-- `no vpn type available!`

I tried to remove vpnc (`apt-get purge vpnc`) and reinstall it, reboot. Nothing worked.

I tried to connect to my network via cli `sudo vpnc` and followed the assistant and it worked.

My **problem** now is that I don't know how to change the settings I made for this `tun0` adapter, how to add another vpn connection and how to manage these...

Is there a way to get gui/networkmanager to work for me or configure the existing tunXYZ adapters adequately for a non-professional linux user? :)

Comment: forgot to mention: also installed "network-manager-vpnc" --> still not working :/